# How to change numbering in remark?

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

I am writing a book on mathematics. I want to get the following text document :
[image]

I have written the following code :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
%\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}


\begin{document}    

\chapter{Number Theory}
\section{Congruence}
\begin{theorem}
Here is my theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{remark}
 Text
\end{remark}


\begin{remark}
 Text
\end{remark}


\begin{remark}
 Text
\end{remark}
\begin{proposition}
 Here is my proposition.
\end{proposition}
\begin{remark}
 Text
\end{remark}


\begin{remark}
 Text
\end{remark}
\begin{lemma}
 Here is my lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{remark}
 Text
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

This produces :
[image]

But I don't like this style. How can I change "remark" number ?  Also I want the font in proposition "normal font".

Comment: This is simply redefining some of the theorem environment parameters. But, a serious question is: why should the subsection number be 1, when there is no subsection at all? And, are you sure, you'd like to confuse your readers when you say you're referring to your first remark somewhere in the text?

Comment: @kan I have understood my mistake. I will update my post soon. But my two problems remains there ?

Comment: I have updated my post.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code that addresses your concerns (but please rethink if you want to confuse your readers! Please!):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{myplain}% name
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below
{\itshape}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\newtheoremstyle{mypro}% name
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below
{}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{myplain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{mypro}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[proposition]
\newtheorem*{remark*}{Remark} %For having unnumbered remarks.  

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\renewcommand{\theremark}{\arabic{remark}}

\begin{document}    

\chapter{Number Theory}
\section{Linear Congruences}
\begin{theorem}
Here is my theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{remark}
 Text
\end{remark}


\begin{remark}
 Text
\end{remark}


\begin{remark}
 Text
\end{remark}
\begin{proposition}
 Here is my proposition.
\end{proposition}
\begin{remark}
 Text
\end{remark}


\begin{remark}
 Text
\end{remark}
\begin{lemma}
 Here is my lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{remark*}
 Text
\end{remark*}

\end{document}
```

The annotations for the theoremstyle are taken verbatim from the AMS guide to `amsthm` (available [here](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf)).

[image: thmsty.png]

Comment: Thank you @kan.My problem is solved partially. +1 for you.

Comment: How can I change remark number of proposition ?

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar Look at my new version of the answer.

Comment: Incase the updated answer resolved your Q kindly [Accept and upvote answers which is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.